# Pacemaker - Cluster does not pass to another node after a disconnected interface

Tags: load-balancing, cluster, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I have the next scenario in Corosync + Pacemaker

**Node1:**

eth0: 10.143.0.21/24

eth1: 10.10.10.1/30 (Corosync Comunication)

eth2: 192.168.5.2/24

**Node2:**

eth0: 10.143.0.22/24

eth1: 10.10.10.2/30 (Corosync Comunication)

eth2: 192.168.5.3/24

**Floating IP's**

eth0: 10.143.0.23/24

eth2: 192.168.5.1/24

The interface eth1 is only use for corosync comunication.

For example I disconnected the network cable from interface eth0 but nothing happens, other example I disconnected the network cable from interface eth2 and I have the same result but I disconnected the network cable from interface eth1 (corosync comunication) and the Floating IP's pass to the other node.

How can I make when disconnecting any interface the resources pass to the other node?

Regards

**UPDATE**

I tested with the following settings

```
crm configure primitive PING-WAN ocf:pacemaker:ping params host_list="10.143.0.1" multiplier="1000" dampen="1s" op monitor interval="1s"
crm configure primitive Failover-WAN ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 params ip=10.143.0.23 nic=eth0 op monitor interval=10s meta is-managed=true
crm configure primitive Failover-LAN ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 params ip=192.168.5.1 nic=eth2 op monitor interval=10s meta is-managed=true
crm configure group Cluster Failover-WAN Failover-LAN
crm configure location Best_Connectivity Cluster rule pingd: defined pingd
```

It works for me, when disconnecting the network cable from the eth0 and losing the ping to the destination 10.143.0.1 (Gateway) resources were moved to the other node but my scenario is 3 interfaces so I decided to add a ping test more

```
crm configure primitive PING-LAN ocf:pacemaker:ping params host_list="192.168.5.4" multiplier="1000" dampen="1s" op monitor interval="1s"
```

But now it is necessary to lose the connection with the two hosts (10.143.0.1 and 192.168.5.4) so that the resources are moved to the other node.

I'm looking for information but I can not make the following scenario work:

If the node loses connectivity to any host that adds to the ping test, the other resources pass to the other node without the need to lose the connectivity of all ping tests at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Pacemaker you care about interfaces failing. Look at the `ocf:pacemaker:ping` resource. You can use that resource-agent to ping other host lists on the different interfaces' networks, and Pacemaker will react if those pings fail.

If you group the `ocf:pacemaker:ping` resources, or use constraints to relate them, to whatever else you're managing in Pacemaker they'll all move together.

Also, I would bet that when you unplugged `eth1` in your previous tests that the IP wasn't "moving", but rather it was being started on BOTH cluster nodes at the same time; to the cluster nodes, they both thought that their peer had gone missing. You were essentially testing what would happen if the cluster partitioned.

On that note, you should definitely configure a second redundant ring in your Corosync config as suggested in another answer, but that isn't going to have the effect you were looking for.

**UPDATE 0:** You should add both IPs to the same `ping` primitive's `host_list` rather than adding an additional `ping` primitive, and set a `failure_score` on that primitive to whatever is acceptable.

From the `ocf:pacemaker:ping` resource agent (`# crm ra info ocf:pacemaker:ping`):

```
...
failure_score (integer):
Resource is failed if the score is less than failure_score.
Default never fails.

host_list* (string): Host list
A space separated list of ping nodes to count.
...
```

Something like: `# crm configure primitive PING-O-DOOM ocf:pacemaker:ping params host_list="10.143.0.1 192.168.5.4" failure_score="2" op monitor interval="10s"`

Comment: I tested what you indicated and I worked but not quite, would you have any idea how to do to add multiple ping test and if you lose connectivity only with one of the ping test the resources are moved? I updated my question, Thanks

Comment: updated in answer. I also tuned down the aggressive pings.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. What you told me worked, now when I disconnect any interface physically the resources pass to the other node. Just one last question, when I disconnect the Corosync comunication interface resources start on both nodes, is there a way to keep it in one? I tried in many ways but I could not do it

Comment: That's called a cluster partition; each node believes its peer is dead. Fencing/STONITH devices are the solution for that. However, you should also have redundant rings setup in your `corosync.conf`. Look at the `rrp_mode` option for the `totem` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure both interfaces in the corosync ring.

Example:

```
pcs cluster auth node1 node2
pcs cluster setup --start --name zfs-cluster zfs-node1,zfs-node1-ext zfs-node2,zfs-node2-ext
```

Where:

```
# Management addresses of both nodes
172.16.40.15    zfs-node1.ewwhite.net zfs-node1
172.16.40.16    zfs-node2.ewwhite.net zfs-node2

# Cluster ring address for heartbeat
192.168.91.1    zfs-node1-ext
192.168.91.2    zfs-node2-ext
```

Comment: This would only mean that now you would have to disconnect both interfaces before the cluster would react to loss of cluster communication. This is regarded as a best practice to help gaurd against cluster splits, but will not make pacemaker move resources just because connectivity to the eth0 network was lost.

Comment: What Dok said is true, set my corosync ring but I have to disconnect the 2 interfaces to move the resources.